# How to execute sql delete query on button click using javascript function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have three files, index.html, database.php, and function.js. In my database.php, I have created a form with a delete button to execute the delete sql query on click. My main purpose is to display a table with records displayed and a delete button on each so that whenever I click the delete button, it executes the SQL query and removes that particular row from the database.

It works fine before I added in ajax into the javascript. Now when delete button is clicked, the whole page just refreshes.

1. How do I execute the delete query on the delete button click using a javascript function that I want to call in my php file without creating/using new files?

I am using vi editor to code so I do not have any means of debugging except IE's developer tools. My javascript file doesn't seem to be working because in the HTML file the form returns a null at

```
      onsubmit="return checkFields()";
```

as stated from the error I received, but it's probably just because there are errors in my javascript file.

P.S. I am new to PHP, javascript, and ajax so do pardon me if I make any careless or obvious mistakes. I also do not know any jQuery or JSON. Any form of help in the simplest explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <form name="infoForm" method="post" onsubmit="return checkFields()"  action="">
            <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="40"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>Address:</td>
                    <td><textarea maxlength="45" name="address"id="address" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  maxlength="20"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input checked type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">Female</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                            Nationality:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select name="nation">
                              <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                              <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                              <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                              <option value="Indoensia">Indonesia</option>
                              <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                            <br><input type="reset" value="Cancel">
                            <input type="submit" name="result" value="Submit"/>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </form>

    <div id="divTable"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the database.php file:

```
<?php

    // Define database parameters //
    DEFINE ('DB_USER' ,'iqwe');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'inqwe123');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'hqwdqq');

    $table_info = "info";

    // Connect to database
    $conn = @mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR die ('Could not connect to Database:'. mysql_error());
    @mysql_select_db (DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not select the Database: '.mysql_error());

    // Delete Row
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){//java script function somewhere
     echo "<script>";
     echo "deleteRow()";
     echo "</script>";

     }

    //Check if phone no. is duplicate and if not, insert data
    if(isset($_POST['result'])){
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $query_string = "select phone from $table_info where phone='$phone'";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_row){
     echo "A same phone number has been found. Please enter a different phone number.";
    }else{
    $query_string = "insert into $table_info(name, address, phone, gender, nation) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['nation']."')";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string);
     }
    }

    // Display table
    $query_string = "select * from $table_info";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num_row){
     echo "<table border=1>";
     echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Phone no.</th><th>Gender</th><th>Nationality</th><th>Created</th><th>Modified</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             echo "<tr><td>", $row['name'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['address'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['phone'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['gender'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['nation'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['createdTime'], "</td>";
             echo "<td>", $row['modifiedTime'], "</td>";
             ?>

            <!--Delete button-->
            <td><form id="delete" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="deleteRow" value="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>"/>
            <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return deleteRow(<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>);"/></td></form></tr>

            <?php
             }
            echo "</table>";
            }
     else{
      echo "0 results";
    }
  ?>

    <form method="post" action="index.html">
    <input type="submit" name="goBack" value="Back"/>
    </form>
```

And here is the function.js file:

```
function checkFields(){
 var name = document.getElementById("name");
 var address = document.getElementById("address");
 var phone = document.getElementById("Phone");

  if(confirm('Do you want to submit')){
   if(name == null, name == ""||address == null, address == ""||phone == null, phone == ""){
    alert("Please fill in all your details.");
    return false;
    }
     else{
     var page = "database.php";
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if(xmlhttp==null){
   alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
   return false;
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
   document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", page, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  return false;
 }
}
 else{
  return false;
 }
}

function deleteRow(id){
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?")){
 //$id = $_POST['user_id'];
 $query_string = "delete from $table_info where user_id='id';
 $result = mysql_query($result) or die ('Could not execute.'. mysql_error());
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `include` function from Php which will help get the html out of the Php files. You may also want to make fonctions and/or classes to encapsulate functionalities and responsibilities of your code, which will help spot the problem. That's not really helping, but the provided code doesn't make me want to dive in... and to really test it as-is, I would need to setup a new database, which I will not do, sorry.

Comment: Well I took a look at the `include` function but I didn't find much that would help. Thanks for the comment anyway @Emileb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing double-quote at the end of this line:

```
$query_string = "delete from $table_info where user_id='id';
```

It should read:

```
$query_string = "delete from $table_info where user_id='id'";
```

There may be other errors as well. You should learn to use your browser's built-in script debugging features (and/or download one if your browser doesn't have one). For example, try Firebug and the Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, my problem lies the same, every time I click the delete button in the table produced by ajax it just refreshes the whole page. Any help on this?